# What is the best way to keep a copy of the local file path when uploading a file from a user's machine in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am writing a batch uploader. The client app allows the user to drag a directory of files (including subdirectories) to be uploaded to the server. My aim is to replicate the local directory structure on the server.

I don't intend to 'actually' create the same directory structure. I will use some sort of reference in the DB to keep track of it. However, when I upload the file I would like PHP to have access to its original file path on the local machine.

I am open to a simple way (some sort of string reference), but I understand a multi-step strategy (upload a 2cd array of local paths?) might be required. I'm looking for advice on the best way to approach the problem rather than a line for line solution.

Comment: You can't get the local path unless utilizing something like Java or flash or user manual typing the path

Comment: You're not talking about issues with getting the file path when dragging files onto *the browser*, right? Your client is some custom app with access to the file paths, your question is just about transporting this information to the server?

Comment: Thats true, the client side app has access to the file system. Its an installed application and I have the full paths to the files. I am storing them as an array. My problem is in getting the local path 'up' to the server so it can be processed and stored in the DB. The eventual aim is to replicate the local directory structure virtually on the server.

Comment: And what's the problem with "upping" the data exactly?

Comment: My hope was that the original path was somehow accessible after the file was uploaded so it would be a simple matter to retrieve it. So first I want to confirm that the right way to do this is to send a second set of data up that describes the original paths of all the files I just uploaded. If thats the case I have to come up with some way to relate the orginial path (some string) of each file I uploaded and the actual file itself. When all is said and done there could be hundreds. Its possible I could have duplicate file names etc.Any advice?